# Color specific area in Venn diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf

I wanted to color a specific area in my Venn diagram specifically where it is marked in the \bar{A} section. Any suggestions?

> 

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, left = 3cm, right = 3cm, top = 2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node at (-3,3.5) {\LARGE\textbf{$\Omega$}};

    \draw (-4,3) rectangle (4,-2);
    \draw (-1,3) .. controls (1,-1) and (1,0) .. (4,-1);

    \node at (2,1) {\LARGE{$A$}};
    \node at (-2,0) {\LARGE{$\bar{A}$}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify the second draw command to this

```
\draw[fill=orange] (-1,3) .. controls (1,-1) and (1,0) .. (4,-1) -- (4,-2) -- (-4,-2) -- (-4,3) --cycle;
```

[image]

Comment: Very good....approved :-)!

Comment: It worked, thank you so much :)